# Updating the reputation help page with more info

Tags: discussion

Currently, the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) page on SO on reputation only shows the basics, such as editing, downvoting, upvoting, getting downvoted, bounties, and spam flags.

However, some more subtle stuff affects reputation too, which isn't mentioned. This includes -

- Removed posts, which reverse the rep gain/loss
- Removed posts which the user recently edited, resulting in -2 rep
- Deleting downvoted posts results in rep gain, but also could eventually result in you getting banned.

I think new users should be told this up front, instead of them having to find out the hard way later.